# Access SharePoint through web API

Tags: azure, sharepoint

I am trying to access SharePoint web API (https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists)
with an access token, that I've successfully received from https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenant/oauth2/v2.0/token.
I receive 401 code in response with:

> {"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}

Inside the response headers I have this stuff:

> x-ms-diagnostics: 3000003;reason="Invalid audience Uri 'api://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/'.";category="invalid_client"

I've created new app in SharePoint site and published it.
It seems to me that some configuration between Azure application and SharePoint are missing.
Please help me!

Comment: Is https://myTenant.sharepoint.com the URL of the site you are trying to access, or does it look more like https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myteamsite?  If so, the url of the webservice is https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myteamsite/_api/web/lists

Comment: Hello, the url is myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myteamsite/_api/web/lists. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same exact problem. The url I tried was `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/teams/[team]/_api/web/lists` but I get the same error. Were you able to resolve this?